# Automate Monitor string in different log files

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-server-2003, scripting, powershell

I have few log files in different servers and I want to check output in the end of those log files for e.g . success: 4000 
 failed: 200
These logs files are getting generated daily and I have to keep track of these numbers. If there is any way I can automate this option instead of going and checking these files and wasting so much of my time.

I want to create some kind of script like 
Go to \serverA\C$\log_07_02_2012.txt and check this line
Go to \serverB\C$\log_07_02_2012.txt and check some other line.

....

and it should give me output from all of these...

Answer (score 0):

Try this out.  I'm sure it needs some modification to get exactly what you are looking for, but is a start.

```
$servers = Get-Content <path to txt file with list of server names>
ForEach ($server in $servers) {
    select-string \\$server\c$\PS\log_$(date -f MM)_$(date -f dd)_$(date -f yyyy).txt -pattern "<pattern in text file you are looking for>" | ForEach {$_.Line}
    }
```